# Computing an iterated integral $\int_{D}(2x+3y) \ dx \ dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the iterated integral $$\int_{D}(2x+3y) \ dx \ dy, \text{ when } D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1\leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 4, x\leqslant0, y \geqslant0 \}$$

Plotting the inequality $1\leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 4$ it seems to be a circle not including the middle part and $2x+3y$ is a plane cutting through the middle of the circle. Also, the solutions for $\mid 1\leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 4$ seems to be $x = \pm 2$ and $y=0$. So the bounds for $x$ would be $[-2, 2]$ right? For $y$ I'm not sure what should I do... Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: $D$ is circular, so try polar coordinates.

Comment: I have that $1 \leqslant r^2 \leqslant 4 \Longrightarrow  \pm 1 \leqslant r \leqslant \pm 2$, but this I already saw from the picture. @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: $r \ge 0$ since it denotes the distance from the origin.  Try changing everything into polar coordinates.  You should get a workable integrand in terms of $r$ and $\theta$, and a region with constant bounds.

Comment: I see the limits for the integral with r would be $[1, 2]$. How can I found the bounds for $\varphi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain $D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1\leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 4, x\leqslant0, y \geqslant0 \}$ can be easily written with polar coordinates as follows.

Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Since $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4$, you get that $r\in [1,2]$. Also, $x\leq 0$ and $y\geq 0$, which means we only have the part of the annulus in the second quadrant, that is, the angle goes from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$. In other words, we can reparametrize $D$ as
\begin{equation}
D=\lbrace (r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid r\in [1,2],\theta\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]\rbrace.
\end{equation}
Hence, the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{D}(2x+3y) \ dx \ dy=\int_1^2\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\,\left(2r\cos\theta+3r\sin\theta\right)r\,d\theta\,dr,
\end{equation}
which can be solved with elementary methods.

Comment: Shouldn't the integrand be multiplied by $r$ also?

Comment: @DanielLi Sure, you're right, let me add that.